# Classes not loading properly within CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

Below is the code which I wrote using CompletableFuture -

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    printResult();
    return "complete future!";
});
```

In the above code, within printResult function I am using some xerces related classes to do some authentication and that is giving me **SAX2 driver class not found error!**

However, when I wrote the same code using Callable, it's working fine -

```
Callable<String> callableFuture = () -> { 
    printResult(); 
    return "callable!";  
};
```

Also, printResult() is working absolutely fine outside CompletableFuture as well.  Just wanted to know if any one here has any idea what's going wrong here. Appreciate your help!

**Edit:** I digged a bit in the logs and this is the actual error message - 
 {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2} | [---] | Error:SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found

Comment: How are you using `callableFuture` in your code?

Comment: using executor service -  executor.submit(callableFuture);

Comment: And what, if you use the same executor service for your `CompletableFuture`, i.e. `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {  printResult();  return "complete future!";  }, executor)`?

Comment: @Holger - I just implemented your question/solution and it worked! Many thanks. Previously I was running the CompletableFuture directly without using executor- completableFuture.get(). It worked after passing the executor to CompletableFuture. Still confused why?

Comment: Apparently, that xerces related class you’re using within `printResult()` depends on the calling thread. The `…Async…` methods of `CompletableFuture` use `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` by default, which uses other threads than your `executor` and those differences seem to be relevant here. In my opinion, code should not have such dependencies on the actual thread, however, such dependencies, like using `Thread.getContextClassLoader()`, are in fact very widespread…

Comment: It makes sense. I have updated my code and it is working fine. Thanks Holger!

Answer (score 1):

`Callable` is just an interface (and `@FunctionalInterface` as well) and it does not assume anything about context in which it will be called.

`CompletableFuture::supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier)` is different, from its docs:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.

So it is possible that in your case, the error you get ("SAX2 driver not found error!") is caused by the fact that when `printResult()` is being executed from the `CompletableFuture`, SAX2 driver has not been loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I manually tried to load the class before printResult() inside CompletableFuture but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may having issue in a JEE/tomcat/spring-boot application.

In such an app, there is multiple ClassLoader and Threads running for booting and load JAR for the framework and other sub-systems.

[CompletableFuture.supplyAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

```
Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() with the value obtained by calling the given Supplier.
```

Because the supplier is running in a JVM managed thread-pool, the `ClassLoader` of the thread unlikely managed by the framework.